# How to add server path in the inventory file - ansible

Tags: ansible

I have access to a specific common share point folder path (Windows machine). From there I need to take files and place into ansible control Linux machine. I have used the below playbook where I am getting error.

```
    - hosts: hosts
      tasks:
      - name: Copy Remote-To-Local (from NAS to ansible)
        synchronize: 
          src=\\xxx.dns.name\files\Q\Global\_ApplicationData\hello.txt 
          dest= /tmp/ansible
```

Please note: I have access for this folder path `\\xxx.dns.name\files\Q\Global\_ApplicationData\`

```
Inventory file
[hosts]
\\xxx.dns.name\files\Q\Global\_ApplicationData\
[hosts:vars]
ansible_user=<myID>
ansible_pass=<mypwd>
ansible_port=5986
ansible_connection=winrm
ansible_winrm_transport=credssp
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation=ignore
```

Error

```
  -bash-4.2$ ansible-playbook -i hosts newplaybook.yml


PLAY [hosts] ************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [\xxx.dns.namefilesQGlobal_ApplicationData]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "credssp: auth method credssp requires a password", "unreachable": true}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you did all required configuration for Windows support already set up as described in [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/intro_windows.html). One thing that seems to be wrong with your inventory file is the fact that you use `\\xxx.dns.name\files\Q\Global\_ApplicationData\` as the host name but you should use the resolvable name of the machine to which you want to connect from the control machine (something like just `xxx.dns.name`). This is also noted in the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/intro_windows.html#inventory).